# Whatsapp Business API: In which case does the contacts field of an inbound message contain more than one contact?

Tags: whatsapp

The WhatsApp documentation states:

> The contacts object provides all the information about the contact.

which also contains the `wa_id` which is

> The WhatsApp ID of the contact.

[Each inbound message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/webhooks/inbound#receiving) has the `contacts` and `messages` fields, but I fail to understand why there would be multiple elements in the `contacts` field. As I understand it the `wa_id` from the contacts object is the sender's id which I should use to send messages back to the user who did send these messages. Also, [none of the examples](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/webhooks/inbound#receiving) in the docs has more than one element in the contacts array.

So far I`m assuming that structure was in use when the business API still supported groups but I did not find anything supporting this assumption.

In which case does the contacts array contain multiple contacts?